# How do you extract the average RGB values from a encoded base64 string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working in the javascript environment. I have an image captured by the cellphone, which gets back as a base64 encoded string. The picture is guaranteed to be an RGB picture, but I do not know how to get back the averages of the r, g and b channels in javascript from the base64 encode string. I have looked online, the getImageData function seems promising but I don't know the inputs and outputs for the function. So what I want to do is make a JS function that takes in a base64 string image and outputs 3 averages. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: show your work, a code snippet in particular

Comment: Neat I'll check out that link!